# Excel: Highlight all instances of a phrase like in notepad++

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, selection, highlighting

If I select a phrase in notepad++ it will highlight all other instances of that phrase.

Is there a way to do this in Excel as well?

Comment: Permanently or temporary ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 CTRL + F That's what I'm thinking IDK about you.

Comment: In a temporary case one will use a modified search, in a permanent case one would use formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that it is possible without writing a decent chunk of code. There may be a plugin for that feature in the online store, but the closest answer to your question appears to be at this link:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/488558-highlight-cells-same-text.html

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward using "conditional formatting."  For example, in Excel 2010, you'll find it on the Home tab of the ribbon:

[image]

You'll be able to type in the phrase you're looking for, and you'll be offered several formatting choices, or the option to define your own.

No coding needed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It works but it's far more complicated than just double-clicking a word to highlight all other instances (like in Notepad++)....

Comment: True,  Notepad++ is wonderful.